# writing 'TAB' character to a text file in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

What do I need to use to write out my TAB character?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the escape character `\t` in a string literal to print a tab:

```
NSString *string = @"This is a tab:\tThis is tabbed!\n";
```

You can put `\t` in any string literal and do with it what you want from there: write it to a file, to `STDOUT`, whatever.